# SharedPrefferences limpando automaticamente

Tags: android

Tenho uma classe que gerencia o sharedpreferrences, percebi que quando eu fecho o aplicativo e abro novamente, as configurações do sharedprefferences são restauradas para o padrão. Quando na verdade o valor deveria ficar salvo, para que eu pudesse pega-lo em outros momentos, correto?

```
public class SessionMananger {
     public SessionMananger(Context context){
                this._context = context;
                pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                editor = pref.edit();
        }

       public void setClientID(String id){
         editor.putString("id",id);
         editor.commit();
        }

      public String getClientID(){
        return pref.getString("id","");
      }
}
```

Comment: Seria legal mostrar como está fazendo essas gravações no `Editor`, mas acredito que a resposta do Tiago já deve resolver o problema.

Answer (score 1):

pelo que estou vendo vc  não esta salvando nada em seu sharedpreferences   eu tenho um exemplo pra vc   eu usei dessa forma em meu aplicativo..
eu criei uma classe de "preferencia"   e fiz isso

```
public class Preferencia {
    public static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(Context context) {
        return context.getSharedPreferences("energy", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    } 

    public static String getlogin(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(context);
        return sharedPref.getString("Login", "");
    }

    //// preferencia de senha
    public static void setsenha(Context context, String senha) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString("Senha", senha);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static String getsenha(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(context);
        return sharedPref.getString("Senha", "");
    }

    public static boolean setcbremember(Context context, boolean a) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("Cbremember", a);
        editor.commit();
        return a;    
    }

    public static boolean getcbremember(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(context);
        return sharedPref.getBoolean("Cbremember", true);
    }    
}
```

e aonde eu quero que salve  algo   faco desse jeito

```
public void btnentrarclick(View currentButton) 
{
    if(cbremember.isChecked()) {
        AcessoLogin ac = new AcessoLogin(Tela_de_Login.this,
                edtlogin.getText().toString(), edtsenha.getText().toString());
        Preferencia.setlogin(Tela_de_Login.this, edtlogin.getText().toString());
        Preferencia.setsenha(Tela_de_Login.this, edtsenha.getText().toString());
        Preferencia.setcbremember(Tela_de_Login.this, cbremember.isChecked());

        ac.execute("");
    }
```

No meu caso  eu salvo login e senha do usuario para que o mesmo não precise ficar digitando toda hora 
e quando eu quiser apagar os dados do meu usuario e senha  faço desse jeito

```
else{
    AcessoLogin ac = new AcessoLogin(Tela_de_Login.this,
                edtlogin.getText().toString(), edtsenha.getText().toString());
        Preferencia.deletar(Tela_de_Login.this, edtlogin.getText().toString());
        Preferencia.deletar(Tela_de_Login.this, edtsenha.getText().toString());

        ac.execute("");
}
```

e na preferencia     tem esses codigos para apagar a  informação caso ele tire a opçao do checkbox    no meu exemplo é claro...

```
//// Deletar preferencia de login e senha
public static void deletar(Context context, String login) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
}
```

espero que eu tenha ajudado..

Comment: Estou salvando sim, desculpe é que não mostrei o código mas eu faço dessa forma mesmo, dando o commit();

Comment: Mas ajudou o codigo que postei pra vc?